# Is it a wordinian?

Tags: code-golf, subsequence, word-search

What is the shortest way to see if an input is a wordinian using any programming language?

A wordinian is a word that contains words of length 1 to the original word's length. For example,

> ### bin
>
> 'I' is a word
>   'in' is a word
>   'bin' is a word

Or,

> ### stage
>
> 'a' is a word
>   'ta' is a word ([yes it is](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=TA))
>   'age' is a word
>   'stag' is a word
>   'stage' is a word

## Input

Your code should take a word and a dictionary as inputs, in any reasonable format.

## Output

The output should be a value to indicate true or false, to tell us if the word is a wordinian.

[For more info on wordinians click here](http://www.wordinian.com/).

[Here is a list of words](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JacquesMarais/ENABLE2K/master/words.txt) that I will be using as inputs and subwords. Also, in response to @xnor, it has to contain subwords of each length, not a chain of subwords. Note that only one word will be used as an input.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I can't put a whole dictionary on here. What if it's any word that exists?

Comment: I'd recommend passing in a dictionary as input.  That way, its easy to come up with test cases (as you can make your own small dictionary)

Comment: Does it just have to contain subwords of each length, or do they have to be a chain where each subword adds one letter to the previous?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I edited my question to supply a list of all words.

Comment: @xnor I updated the question to answer your question.

Comment: @trichoplax Ok thanks. Also, will something like [this list](http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt) work?

Comment: @trichoplax Actually, I think this list should work: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt  
I updated my question to include the new list.

Comment: @trichoplax The new list contains about 479k words. I think that should be enough. How can this question get reopened though?

Comment: @trichoplax Ok thanks for all your help!

Comment: @JacquesMarais This challenge is clear to me, but I'd definitely include some test cases!

Comment: @trichoplax Ok I use the ENABLE2K list now, thanks. So you mean a to take the whole list as an input and find the wordinians, instead of taking one word as an input?

Comment: @JacquesMarais the concept is to take a word *and* a dictionary, and return true if the word is a wordinian (according to the dictionary)

Comment: @NathanMerrill I don't think I understand you correctly now. So you use one word and check through the dictionary to see if the word is a wordinian?

Comment: Yep.  Aka, if your dictionary was ["bin","i"], then "bin" wouldn't be a wordinian because "in" isn't in the dictionary.  The function call would be `func("bin",["bin","i"])`

Comment: Oh, ok, I see @NathanMerrill. Thanks, I'll use that instead. But how can implement that into the question?

Comment: I've edited to suggest how you might word it, rather than trying to discuss it in comments too much. This is just a suggestion so feel free to reverse the edit or amend it to suit your intention.

Comment: What do you mean by "*contains*"? From the examples it seems to be "*contains a substring*" rather than "*contains a subsequence*", but it would be good to make that explicit.

Comment: Can I assume the length of the word and the dictionary (and all entries in the dictionary) have length of at least 1?

Comment: Does the output have to be a _value_? Or can it be something else (such as an array) according to [our definition of truthy/falsy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/36398)?

Comment: @JacquesMarais UrbanDictionary hardly counts as a valid source for the English language.

Comment: Three of the ten answers beat the accepted answer in bytes.  This is a code-golf, and as such the shortest answer should be the accepted answer.  Was there a different winning criterion?

Comment: @JacquesMarais No problem!  For the future, if you want to select the answer with the highest votes us here at PPCG call that a [`Popularity-Contest`](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>20</s> <s>16</s> <s>15</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

Thanks to Leaky Nun for saving 4 bytes!  Unfortunately, I changed the entire method afterwards, but it still helped.

```
gl{lM}#zQlz
```

Expects input as dictionary followed by word.  Outputs True or False.

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=gl%7BlM%7D%23zQlz&input=%5B%22a%22%2C%22ta%22%2C%22tag%22%2C%22age%22%2C%22stag%22%2C%22stage%22%2C%22useless%22%2C%22test%22%5D%0Astage%0A&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
        lz   Collects the length of the word  input
g             and compares it to:
 l             The length of the following:
     # Q        Select all words from the dictionary that
    } z         are contained within the input word.
  lM            Map them to their respective lengths, and
 {              then remove any duplicates.
```

This does not function if the empty string `""` is a valid word.

Comment: `.E` can be replaced with `s`

Comment: `m}kH` can be replaced with `}RH`

Comment: I would just give you [the golfed code](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.Ams%7DReQd.glk.%3Ah&input=%22stage%22%2C%5B%22a%22%2C%22ta%22%2C%22tag%22%2C%22stag%22%2C%22stage%22%2C%22useless%22%2C%22test%22%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 11):

### Python, 52 bytes

```python
lambda w,d:len({len(x)for x in d if x in w})==len(w)
```

An anonymous function that takes a word `w` and dictionary `d`. It takes the words in `d` that are substrings of `w`, makes a set of their lengths, and then checks that there as many distinct lengths as there are letters in `w`.

Comment: Ugh I just wrote the *exact* same thing except I had W instead of x and [ instead of {. +1

Comment: @Dopapp It wouldn't work if you used `[` instead of `{`. `{...}` is a *set comprehension* (The same as `set([...])`).

Comment: @mbomb007, oh right, a set would be needed

Comment: @xnor Sorry for not selecting this answer, but as it's a code golf, I have to select the shortest...

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 108 bytes

```
lambda w,d,r=range:all(any(i in d for i in j)for j in[[w[i:i+s]for i in r(len(w)+1-s)]for s in r(1,len(w))])
```

An anonymous function that takes input, via argument, of a word `w` as a string and a dictionary `d` as a list of strings and returns `True` or `False`.

**How it works**

The first step is a list comprehension that generates a list of lists of all substrings of `w` excluding `w`, grouped by length. For example, for `'stage'`, the list `[['s', 't', 'a', 'g', 'e'], ['st', 'ta', 'ag', 'ge'], ['sta', 'tag', 'age'], ['stag', 'tage']]` is generated. This is achieved by looping over all valid start indices `i` for each substring length `s`, and slicing every `s`-length substring using `w[i:i+s]`. For each list in this list, the presence of each substring in the dictionary is checked; calling `any` returns a hit if at least one match for a given length is found. Finally, calling `all` checks if a match has been found for all substring lengths, and the result of this is returned.

[Try it on Ideone](http://ideone.com/sc90Cb)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 44 bytes

- 7 Bytes off thanks to @NotThatCharles and his set operator tricks!
- 2 bytes off thanks to @Jordan with the Ruby 2.3 safe navigation operator trick `w[x]&.size` :)

```rb
->w,d{[*1..w.size]-d.map{|x|w[x]&.size}==[]}
```

It's an anonymous functions which takes a word `w` and a dictionary (array of words) `d`. Creates two arrays: The first containing the numbers 1 up to and including the length of `w`; The second array is `d` with each word mapped to their size if they are a substring of `w`, otherwise `nil`. Then it does set substraction to check whether the second array contains all element of the first array.

Comment: With the "safe navigation operator" in Ruby 2.3 you can save a couple bytes: `w[x]&.size==i` instead of `x.size==i&&w[x]`.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks @Jordan. Didn't know that one, awesome :)

Comment: you can save another few bytes in your anonymous function (and maybe the full program) by dropping the `uniq` and `-[p]` and using set subtraction instead: `[*1..w.size]-d.map{...}==[]`

Comment: @NotthatCharles That's brilliant! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell <s>v3+</s> v2+, <s>127</s> <s>110</s> <s>70</s> 65 bytes

```
param($a,$d)($d|?{$a-match$_}|select length -U).count-eq$a.length
```

*(I see now that my approach is similar to @xnor's, though I developed it independently)*

Takes input word `$a` and dictionary `$d`, expecting `$d` as an array (see examples below). Loops through the entirety of `$d` and performs a `Where-Object` to pull out the entries where the current word `$_` is a regex `-match` against the input word `$a` (i.e., is the current word a substring of the input word).

We collect all of those substring words and pipe them to `Select-Object` on the `length` parameter and the `-U`nique constraint. That will pull out the unique lengths of each substring. For example, for input word `comb`, this will be an array of `(4,2)` for `('comb','om')`.

We take the `.count` of that resultant array and compare it against the input word's `.length`. If it's equal to, that means that every substring length is in the dictionary, so `$TRUE`, otherwise we're missing at least one, so `$FALSE`. That Boolean value is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

NB - This *should* work in v2+, since the `-in` operator is no longer present, but I've not tested that version.

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\is-it-a-wordinian.ps1 'stage' (gc .\words.txt)
True

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\is-it-a-wordinian.ps1 'metal' (gc .\words.txt)
True

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\is-it-a-wordinian.ps1 'comb' (gc .\words.txt)
False
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 86 bytes

Requires `-E` at no extra cost.

```pl
chop(($s,@d)=<>);for$=(1..($x=length$s)){$-+=!!grep$s=~/$_/,grep$===y///c,@d}say$-==$x
```

Accepts all input via STDIN. First input is target word, rest of input is dictionary. Prints `1` on success, empty string on failure.

#### Usage

```sh
perl -E 'chomp(($s,@d)=<>);for$=(1..($x=length$s)){$-+=!!grep$s=~/$_/,grep$===y///c,@d}say$-==$x' <<< 'stage
a
ta
age
stag
stage'
1
perl -E 'chomp(($s,@d)=<>);for$=(1..($x=length$s)){$-+=!!grep$s=~/$_/,grep$===y///c,@d}say$-==$x' <<< 'stage
a
at
age
stag
stage'

perl -E 'chomp(($s,@d)=<>);for$=(1..($x=length$s)){$-+=!!grep$s=~/$_/,grep$===y///c,@d}say$-==$x' <<< 'bin
i
in
bin'
1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 90 bytes

```
Sort[MemberQ[DictionaryWordQ/@StringPartition[#,t,1],True]~Table~{t,StringLength@#}][[1]]&
```

Uses *Mathematica's* builtin `DictionaryWordQ`.

Taking input `d` as dictionary is 5 bytes shorter, but much slower for long lists:

```
m=MemberQ;Sort[m[d~m~#&/@StringPartition[#,t,1],True]~Table~{t,StringLength@#}][[1]]&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

*1 byte saved using an idea from [@xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89991/36398).*

```
XXgc32>!suz1Gn=
```

Outputs `1` or `0` for truthy or falsy.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyIiPdnYyE6xuLTK0D3P9v9/9eKSxPRUda5q9UR1HfUSCJEOJIsRVCqQLi1OzUktLgZJpxaXqNcCAA)

```
XX      % Take the two inputs implicitly. Apply the second as a regex into the
        % first. Since the second input is a cell array, each of its contents is
        % applied separately as a regex. So for each dictionary word ("sub-word") 
        % this outputs the sub-word if found in the original word, or else an 
        % empty array. Gives a cell array of cells of strings
g       % Remove one level of nestedness
c       % Convert to char. This concatenates all found sub-words as rows of a 2D 
        % char array, padding with spaces as needed
32>!s   % For each row, count how many non-space characters there are. This is 
        % the length of each sub-word
uz      % Number of distinct non-zero elements
1Gn     % Push length of the original word
=       % Are they equal? Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), 68 bytes

```
(w,a)=>new Set((for(x of a)if(~w.search(x))x.length)).size==w.length
```

Using a generator comprehension avoids creating an intermediate array. 73 byte ES6 version:

```
(w,a)=>new Set(a.filter(x=>~w.search(x)).map(x=>x.length)).size==w.length
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

Includes +2 for `-p0`

Give word followed by the dictionary on STDIN:

```
(echo stage; cat dictionary.txt) | ./wordinian.pl
```

(When testing on unix make sure dictionary.txt uses `\n` as line terminator, not `\r\n`)

`wordinian.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p0
s%\G.%!/^.*(.{$+[0]})\H*
\1
/%eg;$_=!//
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ŒÃ€gZLåP
```

Word as first input, dictionary-list as second input.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6KTDzY@a1qRH@RxeGvD/f3FJYnoqV7RSopKOUgmESAeSQEEgWQzhgNUA6dLi1JzU4mKQotTiEqVYAA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/s5ulir6SQmJeioGQPZj5qmwRkFv8/Oulw86OmNelRPoeXBvzX@V9ckpieyhWtlKiko1QCIdKBJFAQSBZDOGA1QLq0ODUntbgYpCi1uEQplispMw@oNRMokJkHJIBcVMESmCAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Œ         # Get all possible substrings of the (implicit) input-string
 Ã        # Only keep the ones which are also in the (implicit) dictionary-list
  €g      # Get the length of each remaining string
    Z     # Push the maximum length (without popping the list)
     L    # Pop and push a list in the range [1, maximum-length]
      å   # Check for each value if it's in the list of lengths
       P  # And check if this is truthy for all
          # (then output the result implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 51 bytes

```
{w,d->w.indices.all{w.windowed(it+1).any{it in d}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9BD4IwDIXv/IpyYouwxKsRTDxz8@B5umkaR0fYdDGE344Dg8EmPbz25X3tw3qDNL6kAXRn2ykklLQDdvId0j2HGp3ff0XFoajgaK3RkqAc@5CrogoCSeFVOyGN6YMIUdqgFUO/2XIh6d2jByRQwzCMtydBI5EYhz6BWBM5RC6U0GmpaiTN@EFEYMN4mv48EeH/PPNmqsW8GrjWoGcZZEtCG@/3htjqRzZR8zmX82QYL0hJ7OlS/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [SQF](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/SQF_syntax), 147 bytes

Using the function-as-a-file format:

```
params["w","d"];a=[];c=count w;for"i"from 1 to c do{a=a+[""];for"j"from 0 to c-i do{q=w select[j,i];if(q in d)then{a set[i-1,q]}}};c==count(a-[""])
```

Call as: `["WORD", DICTIONARY] call NAME_OF_COMPILED_FUNCTION`

Ungolfed:

```
//name parameters
params["w", "d"];
a = []; c = count w;
//for each length of subword
for "i" from 1 to c do {
    //add entry to the `a`
    a = a + [""];
    //for each starting position for that length
    for "j" from 0 to c - i do {
        //get subword
        q = w select [j, i];
        //check if in dictionary
        if(q in d) then {
            //set the entry to the wubword
            a set [i - 1, q]
        }
    }
};
//check if length of word is equal to number of subwords
c == count (a - [""])
```